# Change appearance of 'Series' + 'Number' entries in biblatex' bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Following the style guidelines for an article I'm writing, I need to make sure that the title of the book series is printed in italics, preceded by an equal sign plus a space, and followed by a comma, the number within that series, and a period, and all of that enclosed in parentheses, and no period following the closing parenthesis. E.g.

> Girvan, R. (1931). *Angelsaksisch handboek*. (= *Oudgermaansche handboeken*, 4.) Haarlem: H. D. Tjeenk & Zoon.

Note that it's only the series title that's italicized within the parentheses. The various symbols (`=`, `,`, `.`) and the parentheses themselves are in an upright font.

What command(s) can I include in the preamble of my `.tex` file that will result in such a bibliography?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{girvan1931,
    AUTHOR = "R. Girvan",
    TITLE = "Angelsaksisch handboek",
    YEAR = "1931",
    LOCATION = "Haarlem",
    NUMBER = "4",
    PUBLISHER = "H. D. Tjeenk Willink \& Zoon",
    SERIES = "Oudgermaansche handboeken"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{girvan1931}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like this redefinition of the `bibmacro` `series+number`. But before we do that, we make sure the `series` (is printed in italics [is emphasised]), at least for `book`s, `inbook`s, `collection`s and  `incollection`s.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,collection]{series}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

We then define the `series+number` macro, so it does print the format "(= series, #)", but only if both the series and the number are defined, otherwise a slightly changed standard form of the macro is used.

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{series}} and not test {\iffieldundef{number}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \printtext{=\addspace}%
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{number}%
      \printtext{\addperiod}}
      \nopunct}
    {\printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{number}
     \newunit}}
```

If you absolutely always want to see the `series` in "(= series)" even if no number is present, you might like this redefinition

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printtext{=\addspace}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{number}%
     \printtext{\addperiod}}
     \nopunct}}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{girvan1931,
    AUTHOR = "R. Girvan",
    TITLE = "Angelsaksisch handboek",
    YEAR = "1931",
    LOCATION = "Haarlem",
    NUMBER = "4",
    PUBLISHER = "H. D. Tjeenk Willink \& Zoon",
    SERIES = "Oudgermaansche handboeken"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,collection]{series}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{series}} and not test {\iffieldundef{number}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \printtext{=\addspace}%
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{number}%
      \printtext{\addperiod}}
      \nopunct}
    {\printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{number}
     \newunit}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{girvan1931,wilde,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Note that the `series` for `wilde` is not wrapped into parentheses and preceded by a `=`, it just prints "English and American drama of the Nineteenth Century." with the redefinition, in the second redefinition it will print as "(= English and American drama of the Nineteenth Century.)" which appears slightly odd to me: If a `number` is present the `=` states that the `title` is in a way equivalent to the `number`th book in the `series`, but if no number is present the `=` sign seems to suggest the `title` is equivalent to the whole `series` it appeared in, that, of course is nonsense.

---

A third possibility is to redefine the macro in the following way.
Here, the equal sign is only displayed if a number is available (to avoid some kind of category mistake).

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \iffieldundef{number}
       {}
       {\printtext{=\addspace}}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \iffieldundef{number}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{number}}%
     \printtext{\addperiod}}
     \nopunct}}
```

Comment: I'm testing this out now, but just to quickly add that there should be a period following the # inside the parenthesis, and there should be no period after the parenthesis.

Comment: @Sverre I must have missed that, try the edited answer.

Comment: You're making a very good point about the title of ``series`` when no ``number`` is available (my style guidelines say nothing about this, of course). BUT, I don't think it would be correct in those cases to italicize the title of the series, because then it looks to me like it is a part of the book title. I think the best in this case would be to just remove the equal sign, so that it says "_The Importance of Being Earnest: A Trivial comedy for Serious People_ (English and American drama of the Nineteenth Century.)"

Comment: @Sverre Mhhh, conditional italicisation does not seem right to me, removing the equal sign is possible though.